# Prevent the same row pulled from MSSQL database across multiple sessions

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a call center web application that I wrote in php.  I need a better way of managing access to the client database.  I may have a list of 1000 people who need to be called, and I may have 10 people querying that database at the same time in order to pull a person to call.  What's the best way I can keep the same record from NOT coming up between the people who are calling.

Currently, I grab a record, *then* write to a field on it to indicate that it's locked.  So when the next person queries the DB, it checks to make sure it's not pulling anything that was marked as locked.  This works fine if it's a slow night. When you have a lot of people going at once, it's just not a fast enough way of fixing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please share a bit more details about: _I grab a record, when write to a field on it to indicate that it's locked._

Comment: Sorry, make a grammatical mistake. Meant to say I select a record, then update a field on that record to indicate it's locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you query for the person, you could try doing something loike this instead.

```
     Select yourPerson from yourTable WITH (rowlock, xlock) WHERE yourPersonid = 1;
```

This will give you an exclusive row lock on the person to prevent other people from using the same person concurrently.

Comment: You can learn more about hints like rowlock and xlock at [Table Hints (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

Comment: What might the PHP code be like? Would you hold the transaction open until the caller finishes, and update the record if needed within the same transaction?

Comment: I'd keep that one record locked until the transaction was done. When the transaction finishes, I write information into another table, then would delete that locked record from the first table, so it could never come up again.  Using your answer above, how would I unlock that record to delete it in the end?

Comment: You should add, also, `READPAST` table hint to skip locked rows. So `WITH (rowlock, xlock, readpast)`. And this means, ... queues. Instead, you should use Service Broker ([link #1](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/service-broker-foundations-workbench/), [link #2](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/service-broker-advanced-basics-workbench/)).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that perhaps you are doing something like:

```
declare @id int, @phone varchar(20), @name varchar(100)
select top (1) @id = id, @phone = phone, @name = name
from People
where status = 'awaiting'

update People
set status = 'in_process'
where id = @id --previously grabbed

--- etc.
```

It is not safe, because of some other process could also select the same record before your update statement

In this scenario you can use `update` statement (or `delete`, depending on your logic) with the [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause

```
declare @person table (id int, phone varchar(20), name varchar(100))

update top (1) p
set status = 'in_process'
output inserted.id, inserted.phone, inserted.name into @person
from People p
where status = 'awaiting'
```